# Copiar colunas de linhas correspondentes

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

tenho uma planilha que contém 100 linhas com nome de países e 12 colunas (meses do ano) contendo valores. A minha necessidade é compor uma macro que: varra as colunas e copie para outra planilha de forma que fique o pais na coluna A, e o valor do mes na coluna B um abaixo do outro. Agradeço a ajuda.

Ex:
coluna A - PAIS  | Coluna B - VALOR

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Como que seria? por exemplo: o país1 a é inserido na linha 1 e o país2 na linha 13?

Comment: Olá danieltakeshi, O Fernando acertou em cheio a solução. Agradeço e muito a interação e ajuda de vocês.

Comment: Que bom que sua dúvida foi sanada. Para ajudar a comunidade do SOpt, você poderia [aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A macro abaixo é uma macro genérica para transpor valores que estão organizados em colunas para linhas.

Usando como exemplo a sua pergunta, onde os valores estão organizados em colunas de meses:

```
País         Jan         Fev         Mar 
----------   ----------  ----------  ----------
Brasil       110,00      120,00      130,00 
Alemanha     210,00      220,00      230,00
```

A macro vai gerar uma tabela resultante onde os meses e seus respectivos valores passam a ser exibidos em linha:

```
Pais        Mês  Valor 
----------  ---  ----------
Brasil      Jan  110,00 
Brasil      Fev  120,00 
Brasil      Mar  130,00 
Alemanha    Jan  210,00 
Alemanha    Fev  220,00 
Alemanha    Mar  230,00
```

No seu caso a macro poderá ser chamada da seguinte forma:

```
Transpor "Plan1", "A1:M101", "Plan2", "A1", "Mês", "Valor"
```

**Macro para Transpor Colunas em Linhas**

```
Public Sub Transpor(PlanilhaOrigem As String, IntervaloTabelaOrigem As String, _
                    PlanilhaDestino As String, CelulaDestino As String, _
                    Optional TituloValores1 As String = "Valor1", _
                    Optional TituloValores2 As String = "Valor2")

    Dim rangeTabelaOrigem As Range
    Dim rangeCelulaDestino As Range
    Dim lin As Integer
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim linDest As Integer

    'Definir o intervalo da tabela onde estão os dados de origem (incluindo cabeçalho)
    Set rangeTabelaOrigem = Worksheets(PlanilhaOrigem).Range(IntervaloTabelaOrigem)

    'Definir a célula onde inicia a tabela de destino
    Set rangeCelulaDestino = Worksheets(PlanilhaDestino).Range(CelulaDestino)

    'Montar o cabeçalho da tabela de destino
    rangeCelulaDestino.Value = rangeTabelaOrigem.Cells(1, 1)
    rangeCelulaDestino.Offset(, 1).Value = TituloValores1
    rangeCelulaDestino.Offset(, 2).Value = TituloValores2

    'Percorrer a tabela de origem e preencher a tabela de destino
    For lin = 2 To rangeTabelaOrigem.Rows.Count

        For col = 2 To rangeTabelaOrigem.Columns.Count

            linDest = linDest + 1

            rangeCelulaDestino.Offset(linDest).Value = rangeTabelaOrigem.Cells(lin, 1).Value
            rangeCelulaDestino.Offset(linDest, 1).Value = rangeTabelaOrigem.Cells(1, col).Value
            rangeCelulaDestino.Offset(linDest, 2).Value = rangeTabelaOrigem.Cells(lin, col).Value
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Oi Fernando, obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente. Apenas para dar uma incrementada, notei que o arquivo (recebido externamente e impossibilitado de ser alterado) possui uma linha adicional com o Ano da informação, ou seja, na verdade começa a partir da linha 3 e o ano será incluido também. Mas já consegui avançar e muito. Obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que funcionou @JoseliAlves. Você puderia marcar a resposta como aceita? Obrigado